# What is the max capacity for resource boats?

Tags: boom-beach

In the game you collect resources from your resource generator buildings, and from islands (apart from attacking). The resources from the captured islands are gathered to you via some resource boats (one for each resource).

The longer you wait, the more resources the boats give you. What is the capacity of this ships?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [Boom Beach Wiki](http://boombeach.wikia.com/wiki/Resource_Base):

> These boats can fill up. The capacity of a boat is equal to the
>   combined sum of all your Resource Bases of that Resource type's
>   collectors' capacity. Basically, if one of your Resource Bases'
>   collector fills up, you will have to collect from the boat for that
>   base's collector to start producing again. This means that overall
>   Resource Base production slows down after a few hours (because the
>   lower-level Resource Bases fill up with resources) and stops
>   eventually.

Answer (score 0):

The boats/ships do not have a capacity limit but every island you lose, the amount of resources in the boats/ships will be decreased.

Comment: There is a max capacity for the boats, as sometimes they stop holding more resources. But the amount varies =/